# Why does `ps -p $PPID -o comm=` return different result?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I use the following code to detect the current interactive shell

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ps -p $PPID -o comm=
```

On macOS, returns `-zsh`
On Debian returns `zsh`
On centOS, returns `zsh`

Why is there a `-` symbol? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As the Bash manual says, ...

> A  login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is a -, or
> one started with the --login option.

Most likely your Mac is giving you a login shell, and the others are subshells.